# How can I extract especific strings from a text and put it into an array?

Tags: php

I have a text like

```
Hello {{name}}, I am {{virtual_assistant_name}}, virtual assistant of {{company_name}}.
```

How can I extract this strings inside {{}} and put int into an array?

Comment: Are you using a framework?

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this

Comment: It's a text to send messages to whatsapp api service

Comment: not using any framework. I have tried to find a solution, but found nothing

Comment: @berend how this tool work?

Comment: `str_replace( ['{{name}}', '{{virtual_assistant_name}}', '{{company_name}}'], [$name,$van, $coname], $input_string);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the output required, using a split device I devised when writing a JSON parser.

```
$s='Hello {{name}}, I am {{virtual_assistant_name}}, virtual assistant of {{company_name}}.';

$a=[];
foreach(explode('}}',$s) as $v) {
    $t=explode('{{',$v);
    if (isset($t[1])) $a[]=$t[1];
}

print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => name
    [1] => virtual_assistant_name
    [2] => company_name
)
```

[Teh playground](https://www.tehplayground.com/Rvw7jLS8EBQkCmYj)

It assumes the string is well-formed (i.e. equal number of `{{` to `}}`, and never more of the latter), and doesn't have nesting.

Then `explode` by `}}`, and then `explode` each sub-part by `{{`. If there are 2 parts, the value exists, and so add it to the array.